# Submitting the same form inside the onsubmit function of the form

Tags: javascript, validation

I am making a video game where the player needs to choose a username (maximum 15 characters) I used the `pattern` attribute on the `input` as the first level of  verification. I used the below code as a second level verification just in case someone tries to change the HTML.

**HTML**

```
<form id="guest-form">
    <div class="login-text">Choose a username:</div>
    <input id="guest-username" pattern=".{1,15}" title="max 15 characters" required="required" type="text">
    <input class="login-button" type="submit" value="Play">
</form>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById("guest-form").onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = document.getElementById("guest-username").value;
    if (username.length > 15) {
        document.getElementById("guest-username").setAttribute("pattern", ".{1,15}");
        document.getElementById("guest-form").submit();
    }
}
```

If they did change the HTML the form would resubmit with the original attributes and that would display the error.

The problem is that when the form is submitted the page is reloaded

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("guest-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
});
```

Whatever solution there is, I just don't want to create a custom error message if not needed.

Comment: The html would be helpful as well.

Comment: I added the html

Comment: Attach the function to the `onclick` of the submit button instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the page to reload after submit, just use XHR to send the form to the server and process the response.
[XHR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: That's not the point, when the text of input is does not meet the requirements, each browser displays their own unique error message. The point of resubmitting the form is to display that error message.

Comment: I would, instead of actually submitting the form at first, just use a button, and validate the data on click, if the data is ok, submit the form and if it doesnt, the browser  should display it's error message because you would not have to use preventDefault.

Comment: How about using onkeyup to validate the Form with Javascript while typing and limit the number of characters like this.